# Complex Grid in Ext.js

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, extjs

I try to create a complex grid in Ext.js in MVC architecture.
Lets say i have 2 JSON´s like that:
First:

```
[{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "An ice sculpture",
    "price": 12.50,
    "tags": ["cold", "ice"],
    "dimensions": {
        "length": 7.0,
        "width": 12.0,
        "height": 9.5
    },
    "warehouseLocation": {
        "latitude": -78.75,
        "longitude": 20.4
    }
},
{
    "id": 3,
    "name": "A blue mouse",
    "price": 25.50,
    "dimensions": {
        "length": 3.1,
        "width": 1.0,
        "height": 1.0
    },
    "warehouseLocation": {
        "latitude": 54.4,
        "longitude": -32.7
    }
}]
```

Second

```
[{
"id": 4,
"name": "An ice sculpture",
"price": 14.50,
"tags": ["cold", "ice"],
"dimensions": {
    "length": 12.0,
    "width": 33.0,
    "height": 9.5
},
"warehouseLocation": {
    "latitude": 54.75,
    "longitude": 21.4
}}]
```

Now i want to create a grid like that:

A column which shows in the first row the "length" of Object "id":2, in the second row the "length" of Object "id":3 and in the third row the "length" of Object "id":4.

I hope there are some suggestions...

Comment: Objects don't have a `length` property.

Comment: What do you mean by "two JSON"? Are you making separate requests? Why aren't they combined?

Comment: Yes! these are two seperated requests